# Is there a way to retrieve the proxied destination of a request before the request is fulfilled? (YARP)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy, ms-yarp

Using YARP as a reverse proxy in our API gateway, an authorisation header is applied to each request through a middleware.
E.G.

```
private void SetProxyPipeline(IReverseProxyApplicationBuilder proxyPipeline)
        {
            proxyPipeline.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                var proxyFeature = context.GetReverseProxyFeature();
                // Add to authorisation header here before passing request to intended service
                
                return next();
            });
        }
```

However, now I'm looking for a method of retrieving the intended destination path of this request before `next()` is called.

For example, a request to the gateway
`localhost:3000/service/example1`
This request gets routed to `localhost:3100/api/example1` or `localhost:3200/api/example1` depending on which destination is chosen by YARP.

I've been trying to find a way to see which destination (and full path) YARP has chosen before it completes the request.

`ProxyFeature` offers a ProxiedDestination property, however this only seems to be filled after `next()` is called and the request has been routed.

Available destinations are also offered by `ProxyFeature` however this would only be useful by assuming that there will always be one destination for each route, and wouldn't take into consideration any transforms that are being applied to the request.